# NestJS microservices "Cannot find module"

Tags: node.js, module, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

So, I'm trying to create my first microservice using NestJS, but the moment I try to run it, the service stops with this error:

```
[13:39:21] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\voryi\IdeaProjects\YWA\des_server\services\learning-service\dist\main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: looks like you're trying to run `node dist/main.js` while there's no `main.js`. Check out your `dist` directory

Comment: It actually does generate the main, but I guess that for some reason it can't see/read it...
https://prnt.sc/AZ4-4f7XCI6p

Comment: there's no `main.js` in the first level of `dist` directory, tho. You can define the entry file by adding this to your `nest-cli.json`: `"entryFile": "learning-service/src/main"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you tell me please where can I read how it works so when I face +/- the same problem I'll be able o solve it myself?

Comment: I guess you just need to know how typescript define the destination of your transpiled code. Learn about the following compiler options: `baseUrl`, `rootDir` and `outDir` at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Thanks once again!
How can I mark the question as solved? Or it's some mod's function that only they can do?
If so, shouldn't you post it as an answer rather than comment so it can be marked as an appropriate one?
Sorry, just some questions from the newbie xd

Comment: you can mark my answer as the right one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there's no `main.js` file in the first level of your `dist` directory. You can define the entry file by adding this to your `nest-cli.json`:
`"entryFile": "learning-service/src/main"`
the default is `main`

Comment: Adding an `entryFile` field solved the issue for my monolith.

Answer (score 3):

try `npm run build` and then restart your service

Comment: Didn't work. Gives the same error. But thanks for trying!

Comment: For my case, this is the actual answer

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the main.js file was inside src folder so I had to change the script to:

```
"start:prod": "node dist/src/main"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use monorepo setup and this issue happens whenever I start the nestjs server from non-root folder by mistake.

Usually, removing the dist folder and restarting the nestjs server works for me.

Answer (score -2):

maybe simply use this inside the project,

```
npm i @nestjs/microservices
```